# How to add images to a particular selected row of tablelayout in android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have table layout. We should be able to add rows that containing 3 textviews and 4 imageviews to that tablelayout dynamically when onclick of the **"+"** button. We can able to remove a particular selected row when onclick of **"-"** button. When we select a particular row, we should be able to add images onclick of camera button to that particular row. How to do it. Can anyone please help me..

Comment: So what is your problem? where have you stucked?

Comment: but now the problem is, i cant able to add images to a particular selected row, when onclick of camera button, the capturing images are adding to last row, whatever we added last?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a LayoutInflater to add rows on clicking + button. Or you can add the Views using code.
This is a sample code to add an ImageView to a Table layout dynamically.

```
             private void addImageView()
{
    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(this);
    TableLayout mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    mImageView.setId(getRndId());
    TableRow mTableRow = new TableRow(this);
    mTableRow.setId(getRndId());
    mTableRow.addView(mImageView);
    mTableLayout.addView(mTableRow);

}

/**
 * Gets a random no and checks if its already used in R.java
 * */
protected int getRndId()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int possible_id = rnd.nextInt();
    while(true)
    {
    //  Log.d(TAG, "possible_id=" + possible_id);
        View temp = findViewById(possible_id);
        if ((possible_id>0) && (temp==null))
        {
            return possible_id;
        }
        else
        {
            possible_id = rnd.nextInt();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some example related to that requirement?

Comment: but here we are using tablelayout, instead of listview?